# Problem when "-lm" is used during code compilation

Tags: mpi, compiler-warnings, icc

When I try to compile my objective files, I use the following command:

```
mpicc -lm -lmpi obj1.o obj2.o ../bin/exe
```

But a warning occurs:

```
icc: warning #10315: specifying -lm before files may supercede the Intel math libraray and affect performance.
```

My question is how to solve it this warning? Is there something to replace `-lm`, or just remove it?

Comment: Put it after the source files in the command line as the warning suggests?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ICC, which comes with its own fast math libraries for better vectorization and performance (SVML).

Don't specify `-lm`, or fall back to gcc/clang instead.